How to find the details of government telework?
I've been looking for jobs on USAJOBS, the Federal job site. They make a distinction between "remote" jobs and "telework", but the distinction is not clear to me.
I've read their information pages (much of it in bureaucratese), and as near as I can tell:

"Remote" means I could work from anywhere
"Telework" means I may sometimes work from a remote worksite.
The exact details of telework depend on the government agency that is doing the hiring.

I suppose that I have no choice but to reach out to each agency and ask for the details of each job. But I'm hoping that someone familiar with US federal hiring can tell me, in general:

Do telework jobs usually require one to come to the primary worksite? In other words, is it like a "hybrid" job?
Would the "remote worksite" be, for example, a local branch of the agency?


Every position will be different. The policies will get set by the hiring agency. You would have to reach out and request information. Very few positions are 100% remote in the U.S government, some might have telework policy, but those would still require to come into office at some point. Speaking as someone with almost 20 years in federal service. As there is no universal standard I don’t feel this question can be answered.

@Donald Well, yes, that's why I said "I suppose I have no choice..." and "in general"

Your question cannot be answered since every government agency has different policies; it also depends on the job function.  As of right now, the question is way too broad.  There are 16 main agencies. If the agency deals with classified information, the chances of being able to perform even telework are fairly small. The position description should have everything you need to determine whether telework is possible.

Is there a way to reach out to the agencies? Do they generally have an HR department that I can e-mail, or does it work differently for government agencies?

No; There is no central hiring authority you can reach out to, if you are not already a federal employee.

I meant does each agency have an HR department, not if there was a central government HR department. And if they do, is that what you meant when you said "You would have to reach out and request information"?

Some job positions have contact information. It's not required to submit a job on USA Jobs.  Some jobs on USA Jobs are also submitted on other job websites.  There are also internal websites government employees can use to find positions. This will be my last comment

If you want to know about a given job, look at the specific listing for that job, and/or contract the agency in which that job would be and ask them, just as for any other job. Don't count in there being a useful, consistent, and correctly applied distinction between these terms. And remember that competition for remote jobs is fairly intense, for exactly the same reasons you are considering it; being willing to move may hugely improve your employability.

You can look at the following definition of telework from the U.S. Department of the Interior, and then apply this definition for other government jobs.

The U.S. Department of the Interior has a webpage that says:

Telework is a work flexibility that enables eligible employees to perform their duties from an approved alternative worksite (e.g.
home or telework center).

What is the difference between remote work and telework?   The difference between telework and remote work is the employee’s duty
station.
For remote workers, the remote work location is their official duty
station (e.g., their home).
For teleworkers, their official duty station is the agency worksite
(e.g., Main Interior Building) as they are expected to report to the
regular worksite at least twice a pay period.
Here is the link to their website: https://www.doi.gov/telework#:~:text=Telework%20is%20a%20work%20flexibility,e.g.%20home%20or%20telework%20center.



Now, you can probably guess other government jobs would have similar definitions for telework.
